# Connecting to WCF service from Azure Functions and trouble-shooting assembly bindings

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Where can I see the Assembly that Azure functions is trying to load ? (Like fuslogvw on windows)

**Update**
Update the title as requested to better reflect the accepted answer

**Update**

Changed my code to 'manually' construct the SOAP request using WebClient and it works ... so me thinks somewhere the WCF service proxy is not playing well within the sandbox that is Azure Functions ... Nevertheless I would still like an answer as to how we can see the Assembly binding log views.

**Original Post**

I keep getting the same error :

> 2016-11-17T10:32:44.392 System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The filename,
>   directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x8007007B)
>
> Server stack trace:
>
> at
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32
>   errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
>
> at Microsoft.Win32.Fusion.ReadCache(ArrayList alAssems, String
>   name, UInt32 nFlag)
>
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.EnumerateCache(AssemblyName
>   partialName)
>
> at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.LoadWithPartialNameInternal(AssemblyName
>   an, Evidence securityEvidence, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>
> at System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadWithPartialName(String
>   partialName, Evidence securityEvidence)
>
> at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.LoadGeneratedAssembly(Type
>   type, String defaultNamespace, XmlSerializerImplementation& contract)
>
> at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.FromMappings(XmlMapping[]
>   mappings, Type type)
>
> at
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.XmlSerializerOperationBehavior.Reflector.SerializerGenerationContext.GenerateSerializers()
>
> at
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.XmlSerializerOperationBehavior.Reflector.SerializerGenerationContext.GetSerializer(Int32
>   handle)
>
> at
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.XmlSerializerOperationBehavior.Reflector.MessageInfo.get_BodySerializer()
>
> at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.XmlSerializerOperationFormatter.SerializeBody(XmlDictionaryWriter
>   writer, MessageVersion version, String action, MessageDescription
>   messageDescription, Object returnValue, Object[] parameters, Boolean
>   isRequest)
>
> at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.SerializeBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter
>   writer, MessageVersion version, Object[] parameters, Object
>   returnValue, Boolean isRequest)
>
> at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.OperationFormatterMessage.OperationFormatterBodyWriter.OnWriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter
>   writer)
>
> at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.BodyWriterMessage.OnWriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter
>   writer)
>
> at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.OnWriteMessage(XmlDictionaryWriter
>   writer)
>
> at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncoderFactory.TextMessageEncoder.WriteMessage(Message
>   message, Stream stream)
>
> at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.WriteStreamedMessage(TimeSpan
>   timeout)
>
> at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.Send(TimeSpan timeout)
>
> at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.SendRequest(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout)
>
> at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout)
>
> at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout)
>
> at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
>
> at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
>
> at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:
>
> at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
>
> at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)

Comment: Exact same code works flawlessly in my console app... Does anyone have experience in working with WCF client proxies inside azure functions ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, there is no support to view assembly binding logs. [Enabling diagnostic logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log) will help debug most of the errors. Also take a look at [logging tips and tricks](http://blog.amitapple.com/post/2014/06/azure-website-logging/#.WC4C2forJaQ).

Here is a sample for connecting to a WCF service hosted in Azure from your function:

1. Got to Function App Settings --> Go to Kudu --> Go to D:\home\site\wwwroot\YourFunction
2. Create folder **bin**
3. Upload System.ServiceModel.dll
4. Upload WCF service contract IService1.csx. You can do this from either Kudu or View Files on the portal

   ```
    #r "System.ServiceModel.dll"

    using System.ServiceModel;

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string GetData(int value);

        [OperationContract]
        string WelComeMessage(String name);
    }
   ```
5. Sample queue trigger that invokes WCF endpoint:

   ```
   #r "System.ServiceModel.dll"
   #load "IService1.csx"

   using System;
   using System.ServiceModel;

   public static void Run(string myQueueItem, TraceWriter log)
   {
       log.Info($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {myQueueItem}");

       BasicHttpBinding b = new BasicHttpBinding();
       EndpointAddress ea = new  EndpointAddress("http://YourServiceAddress/service1.svc?wsdl");
       var myChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IService1>(b, ea);
       IService1 client = myChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
       var msg= client.WelComeMessage("HelloWorld");
       ((ICommunicationObject)client).Close();
       log.Info($"Hello from WCF: {msg}");
    }
   ```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Wow Thank you for the explanation , I'm going to try it out now ... Makes sense that we should deploy the Service Model Assembly - Although I would have thought that #r would have taken care of it somehow (GAC or otherwise) ... I think this will work , I'll let you know and I'll mark your answer as the correct one - because I was looking for ways to see the assembly binding logs - and you did answer that , the added bonus is the WCF stuff. Thanks and let you know soonest.

Comment: You need to upload dlls that you need into bin folder except for the assemblies listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#referencing-external-assemblies)

Comment: Can you please update the title to something like: Connecting to WCF service from functions for better discoverability? Thanks!