# How to call WCF in Azure Function?

Tags: azure-functions, wcf-client

Is there step-by-step example how to implement WCF client proxy in Azure Function? I read that we can't consume WCF directly in Azure Function and need to add it first to a class library project. The latest example I found was written in 2017. Is there a more recent example utilizing Visual Studio 2019?

Comment: Is this:https://blog.kloud.com.au/2017/04/17/calling-wcf-client-proxies-in-azure-functions/ what you want? The code is same in VS 2017 and 2019. You also could ref this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40652802/connecting-to-wcf-service-from-azure-functions-and-trouble-shooting-assembly-bin.

Comment: Hi, If the answer is helpful for you, please learn to accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. This is also a way to encourage more community members to help you, thank you!

Comment: Hi, did you get any progresses? Please feel free to reply me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the example tutorial: [Calling WCF client proxies in Azure Functions](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2017/04/17/calling-wcf-client-proxies-in-azure-functions/):

- In this post we will show you how to use a generated WCF client proxy
  from an Azure Function.

There isn't an example which written with [Visual Studio 2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/whats-new-visual-studio-2019?view=vs-2019). In usually, the code is same in VS 2017 and 2019. Visual Studio is just a IDE tool, it won't affect the code changing and running.

Just need note the feature difference in different versions, ref: http://www.webdevelopmenthelp.net/2015/09/new-features-in-visual-studio-2015.html.

HTH.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply. Kloud blog does not seem to be online. Any other resources?

Comment: @user14650387 You're welcome. If I get more resources, I will update you soon. Have a  nice day!